# Best DNNClassifier Configuration for MNIST study in TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow, mnist

I am working on MNIST dataset on TensorFlow with deep neural networks classifier. I am using the following structure for the network.

```
MNIST_DATASET = input_data.read_data_sets(mnist_data_path)
train_data = np.array(MNIST_DATASET.train.images, 'int64')
train_target = np.array(MNIST_DATASET.train.labels, 'int64')
test_data = np.array(MNIST_DATASET.test.images, 'int64')
test_target = np.array(MNIST_DATASET.test.labels, 'int64')

classifier = tf.contrib.learn.DNNClassifier(
    feature_columns=[tf.contrib.layers.real_valued_column("", dimension=784)],
    n_classes=10, #0 to 9 - 10 classes
    hidden_units=[2500, 1000, 1500, 2000, 500],
    model_dir="model"
)

classifier.fit(train_data, train_target, steps=1000)
```

However, I faced with the 40% accuracy when I run the following line.

```
accuracy_score = 100*classifier.evaluate(test_data, test_target)['accuracy']
```

How can I tune the network? I do something wrong? Similar studies retrieved 99% accuracy in academia.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I find an optimum configuration on [GitHub](https://github.com/serengil/tensorflow-101/blob/master/python/HandwrittenDigitsClassification.py).

Firstly, that's not the best configuration. Academic studies [have already reached](https://rodrigob.github.io/are_we_there_yet/build/classification_datasets_results) the 99.79% accuracy on test set.

```
classifier = tf.contrib.learn.DNNClassifier(
    feature_columns=feature_columns
    , n_classes=10
    , hidden_units=[128, 32]
    , optimizer=tf.train.ProximalAdagradOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate)
    , activation_fn = tf.nn.relu
)
```

Also, the following parameters is transfered to the classifier.

```
epoch = 15000
learning_rate = 0.1
batch_size = 40
```

In this way, model classifies 97.83% accuray on test set, and 99.77% accuracy on trainset.

Answer (score 0):

Speaking from experience, it would be a good idea to have no more than 2 hidden layers in fully connected network for MNIST dataset. i.e. `hidden_units=[500, 500]`. That should get to over 90% accuracy.

What is the problem? Extreme number of model parameters. For example, just second hidden layer would require (2500*1000+1000) of parameters. The rule of thumb would be to keep number of trainable parameters somewhat comparable to number of training examples, or it is at least so in classical machine learning. If otherwise, regularize model rigorously.

What steps can be taken here?

- Use simpler model. Decrease number of hidden units, number of layers
- Use model with smaller number of parameters. Convolutional layers, for instance, would generally utilize much smaller number of parameters for the same number of units. For instance 1000 convolutinal neurons with 3x3 kernels would need only 1000*(3*3+1) parameters
- Apply regularization: batch normalization, noise injection into your input, dropout, weight decay would be good examples to start from.